# In The Flight Attendant, how is Miranda alive?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending

In the last episode of The Flight Attendant's first season, Miranda fights with Feliks in an elevator, then is later found lying motionless in a bathtub with Feliks standing over her. It is later made clear that Miranda got out of the room alive.

However, I don't understand how she could possibly be alive. The moments between the elevator scene and the bathtub scene aren't shown, so the viewer has to guess at what happened. Since Feliks and Miranda were out to kill each other, it would make most sense for Feliks to kill Miranda and then drag her body to Cassie's bathroom. However, it would've been very sloppy of him to not check that she was still alive.

I can't really imagine another possible scenario for how Miranda ended up in the bathtub, though.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Radio Times](https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/drama/the-flight-attendant-ending-explained/):

> Unfortunately, when we next see Miranda, **she’s lying unconscious in the bathtub** in Cassie’s hotel room, where Buckley is hiding in wait to ambush Cassie. After a tense struggle, Cassie manages to fend off Buckley before her colleague Shane, who turns out to be a CIA agent, arrives and shoots him. When Cassie later asks Shane whether Miranda received medical attention, Shane tells her that the police didn’t find anyone else in the hotel room.

[Glamour explains](https://www.glamour.com/story/the-flight-attendant-finale-all-your-questions-answered):

> Cassie is confused, and most likely viewers are too. However, Gomez says you weren't seeing things; Miranda was definitely in that bathtub. “**She's a strong, wiry, tenacious assassin**, so I think she probably saw her little exit opportunity when Cassie and Felix were fighting and off she went into the night,” she told us. “I think she had plenty of time to get out of there. And we know she’s not dead.”

Comment: Thanks for the quotes. However, they don't really answer the question of how Miranda went from a deadly knife fight to lying motionless in a bathtub, yet was still alive. Did Feliks keep her alive to enjoy the kill later? That would be inconsistent with his other kills and his "Pavlovian" nature. Did the fight somehow move to Cassie's bathtub and Miranda fell unconscious just before Cassie noticed her shoe in the tub? If that's the case, why didn't Cassie hear anything?

Comment: I agree with @Tin Man: how is Miranda alive? Even if their elevator reached the floor and someone was there, so Felix had to quickly make up a story and take her to Cassie's room, he could easily kill her in Cassie's room. And then just wait. The sight of a dead Miranda would be much more terrifying (and effective) for Cassie, than an unconscious one. Guess it's one of those dramatic licences TV shows use!